# How do I add custom actions in a blade <table>?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a custom table component like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($rows as $row)
      <tr>
        @foreach ($row as $cell)
          <td>
            {{$cell}}
        @endforeach
        @isset($actions)
          <td>
            {{$actions}}
          </td>
        @endisset
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am then using this from a different component like this

```
<x-components.table :columns="['Title', 'Status', 'Description']" :rows="$data">
  <x-slot name="actions">
    //here is where I want to add a custom action that needs to be able to access the $row data
  </x-slot>
</x-components.table>
```

I tried adding the below as I thought using the x-slot would give it access to the scope of the `foreach($rows as $row)`, but I just get an undefined variable error.

```
<a x-on:click="console.log({{row['id']}})>Test</a>
```

So how do I go about being able to add custom actions that have access to the row data that they're for?